# After click on button some Javascript alerts are displayed and some aren't. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

A webpage displays all records from the database table `motocykle` to special container.

It looks like this:

[image]

#### Code

```php-template
<div class="dbmaincontainer">
  <div class="finddbspecificcontainer">
    <div class="finddbimgcontainer">
    <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['img'] ).'"  />';?>
    </div>

    <div class="finddbspecificvalues">
      <div class="findvalue1">
        <label class="blackbold600">MARKA: </label>
        <?php echo $row['mark'];?>
      </div>
      <div class="findvalue1">
        <label class="blackbold600">MODEL: </label>
        <?php echo $row['model'];?>
      </div>
      <div class="findvalue1">
        <label class="blackbold600">POJEMNOŚĆ: </label>
        <?php echo $row['capacity'];?>
        <label class="blackbold600"> CC</label>
      </div>
      <div class="findvalue1">
        <label class="blackbold600">MOC: </label>
        <?php echo $row['power'];?>
        <label class="blackbold600"> KM</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="finddbbutton">
      <button class="button" onclick="alert('<?php echo $row['description'];?>');">Pokaz Opis</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Problem

After clicking the button "Pokaz opis" some alerts are displaying, and some aren't. Where is the problem?

Comment: Do any of the descriptions contain single or double quote? That will cause syntax errors when you substitute them into the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If any of the descriptions contain quotes, substituting it into the HTML will cause errors because those quotes will terminate either the `onclick` attribute or the string argument to `alert()`. You need to encode the quotes to prevent this, this can be done using `htmlentities()`.

```
   <button class="button" onclick="alert('<?php echo htmlentities($row['description'], ENT_QUOTES);?>');">Pokaz Opis</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tray this. I always use for output `htmlspecialchars` when it's not id.
When this is id  `urlencode` with `htmlspecialchars`.

```
function h($string="") {
  return htmlspecialchars($string);
}

<button class="button" onclick="alert('<?php echo h($row['description']); ?>');">Pokaz Opis</button>
```